# Why same query showing different order result in two systems?

Tags: mysql, sql

Two table deploy on different machines, client and server both running same queries but producing different result order. How order is changing? I don't want to use order explicitly.

client

[image]

server

[image]

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql

Comment: If you want a specific order, do `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @jarlh yeah that is right but this is not the question i asked

Comment: Can be several reasons, different data, statistics etc.

Comment: @RomanR. THANKS FOR VALUABLE LINK

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee on order in a result like that. Unless you specify the ORDER BY clause.